# Select text not getting change if there is only 1 option in echmultiselect extension in Yii

Tags: php, jquery, yii, yii-extensions

I am using Yii echmultiselect extension for making multiselect dropdown list.
My code is

```
`$data = CHtml::listData(Tax::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name');
$this->widget('ext.EchMultiSelect.EchMultiSelect', array('model' => $Item, 'dropDownAttribute' => 'tax_id', 'data' => $data, 'dropDownHtmlOptions' => array('class' => 'role-chef-textbox role-textbox'), 'options' => array('header' => true, 'height' => 111, 'checkAllText' => 'All', 'uncheckAllText' => 'None',
//'minWidth'=>350,
// 'position'=>array('my'=>'left top', 'at'=>'left top'),
'selectedList' => true, 'selectedText' => Yii::t('application', '# selected'), 'autoOpen' => false, 'multiple' => true, 'classes' => '', 'filter' => true,)));`
```

which makes multiselect dropdown.

My problem is when there is only 1 option in drop down and I select that drop down,then Select text doesnot get changed to 1 selected,but when ther is 2 or more options and I select 1 of them,then it shows 1 selected.

How can I overcome from this issue.

Comment: check if only single option available then make select text equal to 1 selected after making dropdown.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar my problem is that if there is only one option in multiselect and I select that then it does not affect selected text but if there is more then one option in multiselect and I select that then it change  selected text as 1 selected or 2 selected based on item selected.

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle for it.. with similar conditions

Comment: @Sorry I used php Yii echmultiselect extension.http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/echmultiselect/